# Strange number conversion error in PHP

Tags: php, floating-point

How come the result for

```
intval("19.90"*100)
```

is

```
1989
```

and not `1990` as one would expect (PHP 5.2.14)?

Comment: [PHP Converting to integer](http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting) as @Artefacto mentions it will **always be rounded towards zero**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's because 19.90 is not exactly representable in base 2 and the closest approximation is slightly lower than 19.90.

Namely, this closest approximation is exactly 2^-48 × 0x13E66666666666. You can see its exact value in decimal form [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E-48+%2A+16%5E%5E13E66666666666), if you're interested.

This rounding error is propagated when you multiply by 100. `intval` will force a cast of the float to an integer, and such casts always rounds towards 0, which is why you see `1989`. Use `round` instead.

Comment: but intval won't evaluate the inside numbers until after the multiplication so I think it's the 19.90 in quotations, I believe that messes with PHP's number parsing

Comment: @Rudu Right, fixed. In fact, I don't think it's necessarily true because C89 doesn't require rounding towards 0 (well, it doesn't even require IEEE 754, which would render half my answer wrong), but most (all?) mainstream platforms will do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use bc* function for working with float :

```
$var = bcmul("19.90", "100");
echo intval($var);
```

Comment: Which in the case of what you posted will print exactly the same. You'd need to do `bcmul("19.90", "100")` otherwise you're example throws an error since `bcmul` expects a second parameter, and you're embedding a float instead of a string...

Comment: You still need to make them strings rather than numbers otherwise you're still going to have the float->string conversion issues.  `"19.90"` instead of `19.90`...

Comment: Works well (display 1990) without string conversion on my 5.3.5 php

Answer (score 2):

**intval** converts doubles to integers by truncating the fractional component of the number. When dealing with some values, this can give odd results.  Consider the following:

```
print intval ((0.1 + 0.7) * 10);
```

This will most likely **print out 7**, instead of the **expected value of 8**.

For more information, see the section on floating point numbers in the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/language.types.double.php)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `intval` on a floating point number? I agree with you that the output is a little off but it has to do with the relative inprecision of floating point numbers.

Why not just use `floatval("19.90"*100)` which outputs `1990`

Answer (score 1):

I believe the php doc at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php is omitting the fact that intval will not deliver "the integer value" but the integer (that is non-fractional) part of the number. It does not round.